# CodeIgniter error : Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings using Mongodb database

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I am trying to create a remote mongodb server to work with on my CodeIgniter project.

I have updated my mongodb conf file to

```
// /etc/mongodb.conf
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27017
```

When I access my IP in shell script it working fine.

```
~$ mongo --host 192.168.20.106
```

Result Shown:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: 192.168.20.106:27017/test
Server has startup warnings: 
Mon Nov  2 12:29:34.643 [initandlisten] 
Mon Nov  2 12:29:34.643 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary.
Mon Nov  2 12:29:34.643 [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds are limited to less than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).
Mon Nov  2 12:29:34.643 [initandlisten] **       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/32bit
Mon Nov  2 12:29:34.643 [initandlisten]
```

IN My another PC 192.168.20.107 has CodeIgniter project called **ciproject** config/cimongo.php I added below lines to connect with the remote host server.

```
// Generally localhost
$config['host'] = "192.168.20.106";
// Generally 27017
$config['port'] = 27017;
// The database you want to work on
$config['db'] = "tank_auth";
// Required if Mongo is running in auth mode
$config['user'] = "";
$config['pass'] = "";
/*Defaults to FALSE. If FALSE, the program continues executing without waiting for a database response. If TRUE, the program will wait for the database response and throw a MongoCursorException if the update did not succeed.*/
$config['query_safety'] = TRUE;
//If running in auth mode and the user does not have global read/write then set this to true
$config['db_flag'] = TRUE;
//consider these config only if you want to store the session into mongoDB
//They will be used in MY_Session.php
$config['sess_use_mongo'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_collection_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

Now I want to access this application by using the 192.168.20.107/ciproject
When I access this URL in web its show me error

A Database Error Occurred

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 1232
```

I Already Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726751/remote-connection-to-mongodb-server-using-codeigniter) but not getting any solution.

Comment: you have to define this in `databse.php`

Comment: I have Downloaded this libraries  from here https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php-libraries/ so its default they have provided but I want to use the mongodb as remove server and it can be accessible to the other member system as well by uing IP

Comment: your url is wrong. check and post. i can check that

Comment: I edited please check

Comment: Read this http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-connect-mongodb-with-codeigniter/

Comment: Thanks @Ricky but I was using this previously but some of the mongo array and sub array function was not working properly and I have to update with the cursor & extras featured for mongo So I use the latest version of  librariy

Answer (score 0):

after done with research and with the help of stackoverflow I found solution.

in congif/database.php just make it as FALSE

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

Thanks stackoverflow [Ref Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254049/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided-settin?rq=1):)